# Setting values in an initial block in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I think I may be mis-understanding how the `initial` block works in Verilog.

I have the following bit of code driving hardware sprites:

```
// horizontal and vertical screen position of letters
logic signed [CORDW-1:0]            spr_x[SPR_CNT];
logic signed [CORDW-1:0]            spr_y;

initial begin
    spr_x[0] = 20;
    spr_x[1] = spr_x[0] + 30;
    spr_x[2] = spr_x[1] + 30;
    spr_x[3] = spr_x[2] + 30;
    spr_x[4] = spr_x[3] + 30;
    
    spr_y = 100;

    ...
end

always_comb begin
    spr_y = 16'd100;

    spr_x[0] = 20;
    spr_x[1] = spr_x[0] + 30;
    spr_x[2] = spr_x[1] + 30;
    spr_x[3] = spr_x[2] + 30;
    //spr_x[4] = spr_x[3] + 30;

    ...
end

genvar m;  // for looping over sprite instances  
generate for (m = 0; m < SPR_CNT; m = m + 1) begin : sprite_gen
    sprite spr0 (
        .i_reset_n(i_reset_n),
        .i_clock(i_pixel_clock),
        .i_spr_y(spr_y),
        .i_spr_x(spr_x[m]),
    );
end endgenerate
```

I was under the impression that values assigned inside the `initial` block would stick because they are assigned to `logic` types which keep their values.

In the example above though my last sprite (index 4) does not display at the correct x position because the `spr_x` value is not refreshed in `always_comb`.

I'm surely missing or misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Help me out with what part is illegal here? Apart from the ellipsis this is pretty much the code that Quartus compiles..

Comment: 'no sense' is slightly dramatic but...sure. I added some extra context to the sample code extract. It is basically setting up some coordinates to be passed to a sprite module to display sprites on the screen. The issue I'm having is that unless I refresh the values in `always_comb` they get zeroed out which seems wrong.

One more time if the syntax errors are so obvious, please enlight me.

Comment: initial blocks are intended to set 'initial' values to vars **in simulation**. For sure they can be changed later. Some synthesizers can synthesize initial blocks too. BTW, driving same signal from initial block and always block is considered as multiple drivers.

Comment: Yep, I had totally missed the fact that `initial` was only used in simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not use an `initial` block to drive variables for a synthesis build. Doing so results in unpredictable behavior.  Use `parameter` or `localparam` to make the assignments instead.
- The post has multiple drivers (driven in two processes) on spr_x at t=0.  Its not clear which process will win.
- In simulation, the `always_comb` block gets called at t=0.  Its not possible to know which process (`initial` or `always_comb`) executes first.
- Declaring a 2nd variable spr_x_comb to drive spr_x using `parameter` or `localparam`, because they are set during elaboration prior to t=0 in simulation.
- Use variable spr_x_comb  to fan into the `generate` block.
- Get rid of the assignments to spr_x in the `initial` block.
- Generally, do not set values of variables in an `initial` block for synthesis workflows.  Define `parameter` and `localparam` statements to make these types of assignments.

Comment: All this makes sense. Initially the code did not have anything in `always_comb`, I only added it to debug the problem (i.e. things not driven in `always_comb` loose their values somehow).

Assuming for a second that I do not have any `always_comb`. Should the values set in `initial` remain valid or is it normal that they get zero-ed out after t=0?

I'm staring to think that something else is zeroing them somewhere else but I want to make sure I understand what SHOULD happen first.

Comment: Or instead, is it required/good practice to have those values driven in an `always_comb` at all time?

Comment: Initial values remain set until changed in a simulation worokflow.  In synthesis, the behavior is determined by the synthesis tool vendor and can\will be different across tools and tool versions.  Don't count on it doing anything predictable.

Comment: Ok I got it now... the fact that `initial` is only used by a simulation was a crucial piece of info that I was missing. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Stu Sutherland has written books and papers on the topic of a synthesis subset of Verilog.  [paper](https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf) [other paper](https://dvcon-proceedings.org/wp-content/uploads/can-my-synthesis-compiler-do-that-presentation.pdf)    [book](https://www.amazon.com/RTL-Modeling-SystemVerilog-Simulation-Synthesis/dp/1546776346)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will check them out. Someone pointed me to this also which argues the opposite and that initial should be synthesizable using the toolchain I'm using (Quartus). I guess it's better to play it safe and use a reset signal and/or always_comb. http://billauer.co.il/blog/2018/02/verilog-initial-xst-quartus-vivado/